# Device recognition in epub code

Tags: epub, ibooks, kindle, google-books

I'm hoping to implement buy links in an epub that will recognize the user's device and send them to a specific website based on the device, but I'm not sure where to start in an epub. So if the user is reading on a Kobo device, I want to have them click a link that will recognize the device and send them to whatever href I associated with that device. Same link should send an apple user to the iTunes store page for the book.

Will Media Queries get me what I need or is there some other way, because I believe that this has been done in epubs before.

Answer (score 1):

Send everybody to the same link, which checks the user-agent of the browser (should be different for each brand of device, at least) and forwards them on to the correct place.

Comment: Agree. Have the web server do the media query on the inbound request.